# How to use DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt function in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-administration

I want to encrypt password column in the database and I am trying to use encrypt function present inside `DBMS_CRYPTO` package (have given execute access from sys account to the current user) but I am getting the following error.
Please give me some examples of how to use this function:

```
select DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt('12345', dbms_crypto.DES_CBC_PKCS5, 'A1') from dual;
```

Error:

> ORA-06553: PLS-221: 'DES_CBC_PKCS5' is not a procedure or is undefined
>   06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constant dbms_crypto.DES_CBC_PKCS5 is referenceble on PL/SQL only - not from SQL.

You must replace it with literal value in the SELECT statement.

To get the value use PL/SQL block

```
 begin
   dbms_output.put_line(dbms_crypto.DES_CBC_PKCS5);
 end;
 /
```

.

```
 4353
```

You must also use a longer key

```
 select DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('ABCDEFGH12345'), 4353 /* = dbms_crypto.DES_CBC_PKCS5 */, 'A1A2A3A4A5A6CAFE') from dual;

 9320CBCBD25E8721BD04990A0EAEAF00
```

Comment: The example that you have given works fine. But when I change the text to encrypt, I got the following error: (ORA-01465: invalid hex number
01465. 00000 -  "invalid hex number")   select DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt('ABCDEFGH12345', 4353, 'A1A2A3A4A5A6CAFE') from dual;

Comment: The src parameter must be casted to [RAW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65696). I updateted the example.

Comment: Please tell how to decrypt as well. This is what I have tried so far. I encrypted as u said: select DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('ABCDEFGH12345'), 4353, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('A1A2A3A4A5A6CAFE')) from dual; (Output: 80AA4DEA59B77C433A2142AE9CDD235A). Now I am trying to decrypt to get the actual value: select DBMS_CRYPTO.decrypt('80AA4DEA59B77C433A2142AE9CDD235A', 4353, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('A1A2A3A4A5A6CAFE')) from dual; But I am getting result as 41424344454647483132333435

Comment: working now. Used UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 and got the actual value

Comment: The decrypt must be casted back to varchar:

select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(DBMS_CRYPTO.decrypt('9320CBCBD25E8721BD04990A0EAEAF00', 4353 /* = dbms_crypto.DES_CBC_PKCS5 */, 'A1A2A3A4A5A6CAFE')) from dual;

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is fine, I add just some information about 4353. I saw this request used as is and I noticed this value is not really understood.

4353 is an **addition** of three informations about **encryption used** (des, aes and so on), **block cipher mode of operation** (ecb or cbc) and **padding mode**.

So, **4353** stands for 1 (des) + cbc mode (256) + pkcs5 padding (4096)

If you prefer **aes 256**, you have to use **4356**

**4358** stands for **aes 128**

and so on.

The Oracle page which describes the different parameters is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65692).

Hope this additional information helps everyone understand better **DBMS_CRYPTO**.

Comment: That's correct. If it helps, think of the crypto constant as a bitfield describing all three factors required for symmetric encryption: Algorithm | ChainingMode | Padding. Addition works because of the components making up the field.

Answer (score 3):

Encrypt

```
select DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('ABCDEFGH12345'), 4353 /* = dbms_crypto.DES_CBC_PKCS5 */, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('A1A2A3A4A5A6CAFE')) from dual;
```

Decrypt

```
select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_varchar2(DBMS_CRYPTO.decrypt('80AA4DEA59B77C433A2142AE9CDD235A', 4353, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('A1A2A3A4A5A6CAFE'))) from dual;
```