# Decrypting a value in python which was encrypted using DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt in oracle db

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, dataframe

I have a column ID in oracle which was encrypted like this :

```
select CAST(DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('SECRETSTRING'), 4356 , 'SOMEKEY') AS VARCHAR2(100 char)) as temp from dual;
```

Now i am reading this table in python using pandas. Now I want to decrypt this in python.
I tried several ways, but I am unable decrypt it

Following are the things which I tried:

1)

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Random import get_random_bytes

def decrypty(enc):
    unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[-1:])]
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(__key__, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    return unpad(base64.b64decode(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode('utf8'))
```

this threw an error :
binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (1) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

2)

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

def decrypt(key, enc):
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv = enc[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]), block_size=16)
```

This threw an error related to padding.

Basically if something is encrypted in DB with a key, using the same key I am unable to decrypt it in python. any pointers ?

Comment: `4356` is a meaningless magic number in your code. What encryption algorithm is the equivalent for that number?

Comment: 4356 appears to be `dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes + dbms_crypto.pad_pkcs5 + dbms_crypto.chain_cbc`.

Comment: I didn't find any documentation related to the magic numbers. But this thread has some info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472691/how-to-use-dbms-crypto-encrypt-function-in-oracle.
And yes its ```dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes + dbms_crypto.pad_pkcs5 + dbms_crypto.chain_cbc```

Answer (score 0):

If the database did the encryption I for sure would advice to use the database again for the decryption too, if possible at all.

If it is not possible to use the database for both the encryption and decryption, put them both in the python code.

Keep the code for en/de-cryption close and make the use the same bugs. Also: what is the reason for the encryption? Maybe that data is not meant to be readable for your application.

Comment: The idea was.. we read the data from db (using select query with dbms_cryto functions on few columns) , then we generate a file and send it to users. They would use that file for some predictive analysis and send us back a file. Then i would decrypt the same